# how download file with okhttp library in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I need download and save file only with **'okhttp'** library in **'node js'** and not in java. but I don't know way to save my file on my computer. I need to use only okhttp library. please help me.

okhttp: https://www.npmjs.com/package/okhttp

```
const okhttp = require('okhttp');

var MimeBuilder = okhttp.MimeBuilder;
var Request = okhttp.Request;
var RequestBody = okhttp.RequestBody;
var RequestBuilder = okhttp.RequestBuilder;
var FormEncodingBuilder = okhttp.FormEncodingBuilder;
var MultiPartBuilder = okhttp.MultiPartBuilder;

new RequestBuilder().GET('http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/pushpin/blue-pushpin.png').bufferResponse().buildAndExecute().then(onComplete).catch(onError);

function onComplete(msg) {
    console.log('success');

    // !!!!!!!
    // !!!!!!!
    // now I need save blue-pushpin.png in my computer !
    // !!!!!!!
    // !!!!!!!
}

function onError(err) {
    console.log('error');
}
```

Comment: When learning a library, the first thing I do is start debugging. Put a breakpoint on `onComplete` and see what `msg` contains. [From the documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/okhttp#guide) it appears to have a `data` property. I'd look at that. If it's an array of numbers, it's probably a byte array. Then I'd look up how to save a byte array to a file...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First require **fs** (filesystem). The response data is available at `msg.data`; pass that to `fs.writeFileSync` along with the filename.

```js
const fs = require('fs');
// ...
function onComplete(msg) {
    console.log('success');
    fs.writeFileSync('blue-pushpin.png', msg.data);
}
```